# password dont change in views.py on django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to change a user's password on my views.py and whenever I change the password, I lose my connection and access to my account

my view.py:

```
 user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id) 
 user.password = make_password(request.POST.get("password")) 
 user.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `User` object normally has a [**`.set_password(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password), so you can update that password with:

```
request.user.set_password(request.POST['password'])
request.user.save()
```

You can omit fetching the user object, since `request.user` aleady does that. Using `user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)` is thus an extra query that only is equivalent to `request.user`.

Answer (score 2):

try using `set_password` instead of `make_password` like that

```
user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id) 
user.password = set_password(request.POST.get("password")) 
user.save()
```

The following is an explanation provided by the Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords